# Update table values by CSV files which is huge PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to update the table which contains more than 10k records, through CSV file in server. Problem Is It shows "Server Timeout" or "Error after a few minutes".

I Have added this lines

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
```

before

```
$this->db->where('part_no',$insert_csv['part_no']);
$this->db->update('mst_parts', $data4);
```

I am Getting This Error

"This page isn’t working
'xxxxxxxx.com' took too long to respond.
HTTP ERROR 504"

Comment: use `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`

Comment: it didn't work, shows timeout in server

Comment: than you need to config your server `max execute time`

Comment: Thank You I will try :).

Comment: I am Getting This Error
"This page isn’t working 'xxxxxxxx.com' took too long to respond. HTTP ERROR 504" after changing max_excution_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the CSV source by chunks, for example reading only 1000 rows at a time like:

```
$startLine = 1;
$file = new SplFileObject('source.csv');
$file->seek($startLine-1);
echo $file->current();
```

And the next run you should increment `$startLine`.

Documentation: [`SplFileObject::seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php)

Comment: can u explain me please, how I can implement it to update

Comment: @VishalRevadi How do you run your script currently? Is this a cron job?

Comment: No, the script is not scheduled one, whenever the user needs to update the price he will update it. Through Admin Pannel .

Comment: the issue is probably also related to the database updates (over "10k records")

Comment: Still, I wouldn't recommend setting `max_execution_time` to `0`, I'd go with a scheduled job. Also, if you can perform this operation in batches, you can ease the load on the DB too.

Comment: I am Getting This Error
"This page isn’t working 'xxxxxxxx.com' took too long to respond. HTTP ERROR 504" after changing max_excution_time .